# Track/intercept method call

Tags: aop, intercept

I want to intercept a method call (usually .net API).

How can this be achived?

I have seen AOP/ContextBoundObject by some googling, but all those requires the class to be derived from ContextBoundObject.

I want to intercept MessageBox.Show Which i cannot modify.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is by using run-time weaving. In .NET the only project I'm familiar with that does  that is [CThru](http://cthru.codeplex.com/) built on top a commercial product called Typemock Isolator (I've used to work there)